# Make a menu with the id of the sections with php?

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, menu, dynamically-generated

I'm very noob in php.
I want create a page with menu dynamically.

If in my code there are:

```
<section id="one" >...</section>
<section id="two" >...</section>
<section id="three" >...</section>
```

I want generate this menu:

```
<li ><a  id="menu-one" href="#one"> <span> One </span></a></li>
<li ><a  id="menu-two" href="#two"> <span> Two </span></a></li>
<li ><a  id="menu-three" href="#three"> <span> Three </span></a></li>
```

It's very easy but i've tried without succeed in this way:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://mysite.it');
foreach($html->find('section') as $element){ 
       $idSection=$element->id;
       $menuElement .= '<li><a id="menu-'.$idSection.'" href="#'.$idSection.'" ><span>'.$idSection.'</span></a></li>';
       echo '<ul>'.$menuElement.'</ul>';
       }
```

EDIT: this could generate an array of section but doesn't work. Is it wrong?

```
$els = $document->getElementsByTagName('section');
```

Thanks!

Comment: "i've tried without succeed" is a VERY good sign. But if you show us what you've typed so far (even if unsuccessful) we will be able to point you the best solution for the problem. As it is, it's too broad to be answered.

Comment: you want the list to be generated inside their respective sections or as a separate div?

Comment: @noob inside their respective sections! (that are in the top of the page, instead of the sectors that are in the half page)

Comment: @STTLCU excuse me for my inaccuracy, i'm adding the code.

Comment: you definitely want `echo '<ul>'.$menuElement.'</ul>';` OUTSIDE the `foreach()` loop

Comment: @neokio ok, but how can i get an array of id from sections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you have ONE ul and many li

```
echo '<ul>'
foreach($html->find('section') as $element){ 
       $idSection=$element->id;
       $menuElement .= '<li><a id="menu-'.$idSection.'" href="#'.$idSection.'" ><span>'.$idSection.'</span></a></li>';
       echo $menuElement;
       }
echo '</ul>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this ...

```
$sections = array(
    'one'   => 'Something',
    'two'   => 'Something Else',
    'three' => 'Something Awesome'
    );

// output <section>s
foreach ($sections as $k=>$v) {
    echo '<section id="'. $v .'">'. $v .'</section>';
}

// output menu
foreach ($sections as $k=>$v) {
    echo '<li ><a id="menu-'. $k .'" href="#'. $k .'"> <span>'. $v .'</span></a></li>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Your answer is like that of noob, check my answer in his.

Comment: then you really need to mention wordpress, or at very least add a wordpress tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this an little change to neokio code the gives what you're looking gor:

```
$sections = array('one','two','three');

// output <section>s
foreach ($sections as $section) {
    echo '<section id="'. $section .'"><li ><a id="menu-'. $section .'" href="#'. $section .'"> <span>'. $section .'</span></a></li></section>';
}
```

Comment: thanks, i've already thought this but i don't know the sections. 
This is for wordpress theme, the menu is in the header but the sections are in the content!